# c# Trying to understand another way this OOP can be programmed

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented

I am very new to C# and I am trying out OOP programming following a book. This is the current code I have and it works but I am wondering if this can be done another way. 
I think that set and get methods can be done in another way

```
using System;

public class radio
{
    private int count = 0;

    public radio() { count = 0; }
    public int Counts
    {
        set { this.count = value; }
        get { return this.count; }
    }
}

public class television
{
    private int count = 0;

    public television() { count = 0; }
    public int Counts
    {
        set { this.count = value; }
        get { return this.count; }
    }
}

public class computer
{
    public computer() { count = 0; }
    private int count = 0;
    public int Counts
    {
        set { this.count = value; }
        get { return this.count; }
    }
}

public class warehouse
{
    radio r = new radio();
    television tv = new television();
    computer cp = new computer();

    public warehouse()
    {
        r.Counts = 0;
        tv.Counts = 0;
        cp.Counts = 0;
    }
    public void addRadio()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the number of Radio to add : ");
        r.Counts +=  Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void addTV()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the number of TV to add : ");
        tv.Counts += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void addComp()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the number of Computers to add : ");
        cp.Counts += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void showContents()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Number of radios are {0}, TV are {1}, Computer are {2},", r.Counts, tv.Counts, cp.Counts);
    }

}

public class main
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        warehouse wh1 = new warehouse();
        wh1.addRadio();
        wh1.addComp();
        wh1.addTV();
        wh1.showContents();
    }
}
```

Would there be another way to code this by not creating a new instances of below inside warehouse class?

```
radio r = new radio();
television tv = new television();
computer cp = new computer();
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You'll need to explain what you mean by "this" — what task does this code accomplish? See [ask].

Comment: While OP does not provide a detailed description of what he does, the code in question is not a rocket science either. I think it is fairly self-descriptive and I see no reason to close this question or down-vote it to oblivion.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You should use `PascalCase` for classes and methods, see [capitalisation conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).

2) You can use [auto-properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties), if you do not need any additional logic in setter or getter.

3) You should probably use singular tense for `Count`.

4) Integer fields are equal to 0 by default, you do not have to set them in constructor explicitly.

If you take all this into consideration, your `radio` class should look like:

```
public class Radio
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

---

A few alternative approaches:

1) Use single class for all your items:

```
class WarehouseItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; } 
}

class Warehouse
{
    private WarehouseItem computer;
    private WarehouseItem television;

    public Warehouse()
    {
        computer = new WarehouseItem { Name = "Computer" };
        television = new WarehouseItem { Name = "TV" };
    }

    ...
}
```

2) It will make more sense to use collections (such as [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)) to store warehouse items. I suggest you try implementing it yourself, once you are familiar with lists and arrays.

Comment: Additionally, I suggest removing `Count` from `WarehouseItem`. It's not item's attribute. It's `Warehouse`s concern to know the counts of each item, and that it will get through item `List`s.